# Pine Script - Exit When Open Price > Entry Price "aka first profitable open"

Tags: exit, pine-script

Thank you once again in advance for your assistance.

Trying to get market order to execute at first profitable open

As recommended, tried several 'process_orders_on_close'.  Set to true, fixes original problem of exiting one bar late (perfect!)  But, it breaks the entry, first image below, in that entry is on condition as opposed to bar after condition is met.  Image One below.

[![Image One][1]][1]

For image two, the intent was to toggle 'process_orders_on_close' from "na" to "true".  Fixed entry but original problem exiting one bar late returns. Results and code in Image Two below.

[![Image Two][2]][2]

Thank you once again.

```
//CODE FOR IMAGE ONE
//@version=4 
strategy(title="Pattern Tester - FPO)", process_orders_on_close = true, 
     overlay=true)
OS = (high > high[1] and low < low[1] and close < close[1])

if (OS)
    process_orders_on_close = true, strategy.entry(id="FPO", long=true)

if strategy.position_size > 0 
    strategy.close("FPO", when = open > strategy.position_avg_price)

//CODE FOR IMAGE TWO
//@version=4 
strategy(title="Pattern Tester - FPO)", process_orders_on_close = na, 
     overlay=true)
OS = (high > high[1] and low < low[1] and close < close[1])

if (OS)
    strategy.entry(id="FPO", long=true)

if strategy.position_size > 0 
    process_orders_on_close = true, strategy.close("FPO", when = open > strategy.position_avg_price)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VLcQ.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcXsZ.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ``` before and after your code for monospace.

You can use `process_orders_on_close=true` with your `strategy()` declaration statement.

Comment: Thank you!  appreciate the help.

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately programming is not my native language.  ;)